# Where can I find an accurate list of IATA meal codes?

Tags: airline-operations, iata

I'm trying to "compile" single list of IATA meal codes. By using different airlines and data sources I have found many meal codes. However, I have also found problems with codes that are used to mean different things, or different codes used to mean the same thing. For example:

1. On [Cathay Pacific's special meal page](http://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_HK/travel-information/inflight/food-and-beverages/special-meals.html) I have found an information, that both `Non-Beef Meal` and `Liquid Diet Meal` are using the same code of `SPML`. These meal types seems to be far different. How to understand this? A bug on CP's page? To make things more complicated, another source uses `SPML` code for `Special Meal or Specify Meal`.
2. Cathay Pacific uses `VGML` for `Vegetarian Vegan Meal` (*Strict vegetarian food with high protein, rich iron and high calcium*). Other source uses `VVML` code for this meal type and have `VGML` code reserved for `Vegetarian Non-Dairy Meal`. Is there any difference between these two meal types and if yes, then which code is correct / official according to IATA.

Help with the above two examples would be appreciated. However, my main question is:
**Where can I find official IATA codes for food?**

If there is any "ultimate source", that we can / should use for this purpose (ignoring airline's specific listings, as in case of Cathay Pacific)? If so, then please, provide a link to it.

**EDIT**: *Please, consider above paragraph. This question asks official IATA meal list, not about airline-specific regulations.*

Comment: I have, of course, contacted Cathay Pacific to ask them the same question as in point one, but received automated response including "_one of our team members will contact you within 14 days_". I have a small hope, that I get some answer here a bit faster than within two weeks! :>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because how airlines code and load food onto their aircraft is not within the scope defined in the [help centre.](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: On point one, I'd guess 'SPML' is effectively a flag saying "it's complicated, check attached paperwork" rather than the actual meal description...

Comment: "How airlines code and load food onto their aircraft" is certainly not within the scope of this site. The problem is, that this question asks, where I can find official IATA codes for food. And, no, it does not ask about how airlines load food onto their aircraft. I think, you have a slight problem with your translator / interpreter. Voting to reopen.

Comment: This isn't anything that's come from IATA - the airlines choose/use their own codes and they're part of the airlines booking systems. SPML is fairly generic and used by most airlines, but how they store the "details" of this varies between airlines. Some use other codes, others will add remarks to the PNR or attach additional paperwork

Comment: I'm voting to close this question again because it's not within the scope defined on our [scope page](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and also because it's about resource location, which is explicitly off-topic for this SE (and most others, too, except [opendata.se] and [softwarerecs.se].) Whether it's from IATA or not, I don't see how being from IATA makes it any more on topic than being from a particular airline. IATA is just an industry trade group of airlines; it is not a regulatory body.

Comment: Well, this question is about IATA codes. And it is wrong. It was closed two times. In the light of this, I still wonder, how it is possible, that this question os wrong and all other `iata`-tagged questions are OK? There is even some kind of dump speculation question about IATA numbers pool running out, which definitely is out of scope here and should be asked on mathematical-like SE site, but... forget it. I'm tired explaining, that my question is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPML is Special Meal, differs from airline to airline.

VGML is vegan, i.e. not even dairy products are used. Unlike vegetarian were animal products can be used, say eggs or milk.

Source: International Air Transport Association. "[Cabin Operations Safety Best Practices Guide](https://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/3996.pdf)." (2017).