# Is there a standard that defines all Special Service Requests?

Tags: commercial-aviation

I'm wondering if there's an international standard set of SSR codes. I see some references to IATA standardizing these, however, I can't find a reference to where IATA would publish these codes.

Comment: Just to be sure .. "SSR code" usually refers to a transponder code (secondary surveillance radar). Is this what you are talking about, or is it something else entirely?

Comment: @Hougaard see the question title. I'm referring to the special service request codes referring to passenger requests, such as special meal requests (LFML - low fat meal) or disabilities such as deafness (DEAF).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find an accurate list of IATA meal codes?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27513/where-can-i-find-an-accurate-list-of-iata-meal-codes)

Comment: @fooot note that I'm asking whether there's a body who regulates all SSR codes. Not just those for food.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... however, I can't find a reference to where IATA would publish these codes.

You can find it [here](http://www.iata.org/publications/Pages/standards-manuals.aspx).

Before committing to the purchase of the document, check the free Table of Contents to make sure it has what you want.